# Replace multiple values in a list in R

Tags: r, list, matrix

If I have:

```
mylist <- lapply(1:10, function(x) matrix(NA, nrow=2, ncol=2))
```

And I want to replace, for example, the first, second and fifth element in the list with a:

```
mymatrix=cbind(c(1,1),c(1,1))
```

What can I do? I tried with:

```
mylist[c(1,2,5)]=mymatrix
```

But I can't substitute the new matrix because it's another list and with the `[[]]` I can only access to one element.

I think I have to use the `lapply` function but I can't figure out in which way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
mylist[c(1, 2, 5)] <- lapply(mylist[c(1, 2, 5)], function(x) x <- mymatrix)
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to @jaSf but faster and "cleaner":

```
idx <- c(1, 2, 3)
mylist[idx] <- list(mymatrix)
```

microbenchmark:

```
Unit: nanoseconds
    expr  min   lq     mean median   uq     max neval cld
    this  687  828 1135.152    959 1127 2787458 1e+05  a 
    jaSf 2982 3575 4482.867   4034 4535 2979424 1e+05   b
```

Otherwise would recommend using `modifyList()` to update named lists like:

```
foo <- list(a = 1, b = list(c = "a", d = FALSE))
bar <- modifyList(foo, list(e = 2, b = list(d = TRUE)))
str(foo)
str(bar)
```

Comment: nanoseconds benchmarks are meaningless in R although your solution is indeed better

Comment: Sure but this replacement is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be using just `far-loop` as:

```
for(i in c(1,2,5)){
  mylist[[i]] <- mymatrix
}
```

Comment: I implemented this but it's more computational expensive than jaySf solution,am i right?

Comment: @gdlzzzz Good point. Let me do some benchmark on performance.

Comment: @gdlzzzz Benchmark on computation time is not consistent in result. Sometime one method is faster than other. But `lapply` based solution is more elegant considering concise code.

Comment: @gdlzzzz This is not a more computational expensive than jaySf solution. Why would you think so?

Comment: @gdlzzzz I didnt say that. I mentioned that the result using `microbenchmark` were not consistent. I tried with different length of list and   replacement vectors. I'm not sure about the reason.